# Setting the result of an if statement

Tags: php, if-statement, echo

I am displaying a user's profile image. I have created an if statement to post a default profile image if a user has not updated their own. This is all working, but what I cannot figure out is how to echo or call for each without getting an error for the one not set.

For instance, if they do have a profile picture set, it posts fine, but then I get an error that the other variable is not defined and vise versa.

How should I be calling for this or what changes should I make in my code?

```
        $pics = array();
        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $pics[] = $profilePic;
        }
        if ($profilePic === NULL) {
            $default_profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';
        } else {
            $set_profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src=" '.$profilePic.'">';
        }
  }
?>
<nav id="nav-panel">
    <div id="nav-container">
            <div id="welcome">
                <?php echo $default_profile_img; 
                echo $set_profile_img; ?>
```

EDIT:

How profilepic gets defined:

```
$sql = "
  SELECT *
  FROM profile_img
  WHERE user_id = ?
  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
  ";
if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $user_id);
        $stmt->execute();
        if (!$stmt->errno) {
            // Handle error here
        }
        $stmt->bind_result($id, $user_id, $profilePic);
```

Comment: where/how does $profilePic get defined?  and why use TWO different vars for the profile pic, and then output BOTH, regardless of which one got defined? you should have ONE variable, since both can't exist at the same time. you either have a profile pic, or you don't. `if() { $pic = 'x' } else { $pic = 'y'} echo $pic;`

Comment: lots of different ways to handle this. 1) you could simply rename `$default_profile_img` to `$set_profile_img`. 2) you could initialize both variables with empty values before assignment. 3) you could double check before outputting: `echo isset($set_profile_img) ? $set_profile_img : '';`

Comment: @MarcB I added how $profilepic gets defined to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add **$default_profile_img = null;** and **$set_profile_img = null;** at the top of php code.

```
$default_profile_img = null;
$set_profile_img = null;
$pics = array();
    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        $pics[] = $profilePic;
    }
    if ($profilePic === NULL) {
        $default_profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';
    } else {
        $set_profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src=" '.$profilePic.'">';
    }
}
?>
<nav id="nav-panel">
<div id="nav-container">
        <div id="welcome">
            <?php echo $default_profile_img; 
            echo $set_profile_img; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to initialize the variables before the `if..else` statements  so that it won't be undefined when you try to echo both of them.

```
$profile_img = "";
$default_profile_img = "";

if (...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. There is no need to use two different variables. This way,  you won't get the warning.

```
$pics = array();
while ($stmt->fetch()) {
    $pics[] = $profilePic;
}
if (!isset($profilePic) OR $profilePic === NULL) {
    $profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src="profile_images/default.jpg">';
} else {
    $profile_img = '<img class="welcome-pic" src=" '.$profilePic.'">';
}
}
?>
<nav id="nav-panel">
    <div id="nav-container">
        <div id="welcome">
            <?php echo $profile_img; ?>
```